# How to write a for loop in Oracle sqlplus?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a for loop in Oracle sqlplus interface. When writing the loop statement an pressing enter, I get an error:

```
SQL> for i in 1..10 loop
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "for i in 1..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL>
```

Is there something wrong with my for loop clause?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For loop is a PL/SQL construct.  Try wrapping your PL/SQL in BEGIN/END block.

If you need to declare variables, start with a DECLARE.  Something like this:

```
set serveroutput on
begin
  for a in 1..10 loop
    dbms_output.put_line('a='||to_char(a));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Hope that helps.

PS Note that set serveroutput on is a SQL*Plus command, and not part of PL/SQL.  It just turns on output so you'll see the output from the dbms_output.put_line() function.

Comment: this one is for oracle sqlplus interface, not for PL/SQL block

Comment: What are you talking about?  He's working from SQL*Plus, trying to execute PL/SQL, which is exactly what my question answered, did it not?

Comment: There's no need for the `declare` section `a` is implicitly defined.

Comment: You're absolutely right, Ben.  I corrected the code above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

sqlplus isn't a language but an interface to Oracle in which you can enter SQL or PL/SQL.

In this case, use a simple pl/sql anonymous block

```
begin
  for i in 1..10
  loop
    -- some great stuff goes here

  end loop;
end
/
```

Comment: Sqlplus is a language, a kind of scripting language with access to the database and the OS shell, but it's not a fully fledged _programming_ language.