# Changing multiple actions chained into sqlplus to for loop in a bash script

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I have this script which is obviously inefficient:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 1 10);
do
  echo "CREATE TABLE testbenny_$i (id NUMBER NOT NULL);
  ! sleep 10
  select * from testbenny_$i;
  ! sleep 10
  select * from testbenny_$i;
  ! sleep 10
  select * from testbenny_$i;
  ! sleep 10
  select * from testbenny_$i;
  ! sleep 10
  DROP TABLE testbenny_$i;" | sqlplus system/passwd &
done
```

I have one repetitive action I tried to enclose in a FOR loop but couldn't.

```
  select * from testbenny_$i;
  ! sleep 10
```

I can't find the correct syntax to change it to a FOR. Working on Oracle 12.

Comment: Might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350666/how-to-write-a-for-loop-in-oracle-sqlplus

Comment: Yeah, copied the example from there, though our needs are a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

Try the oracle `sleep` method as following:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 1 10);
do
  echo "CREATE TABLE testbenny_$i (id NUMBER NOT NULL);
  sys.DBMS_SESSION.sleep(10);
  Begin
  For var in 1..4 loop
  select * from testbenny_$i;
  sys.DBMS_SESSION.sleep(10)
  End loop;
  End;
  /
  DROP TABLE testbenny_$i;" | sqlplus system/passwd &
done
```

I have given just an example of how to use `sys.DBMS_SESSION.sleep(10)` method. Use it in your code according to your requirement.